# Exam Class : With Question with images and border

Tags: graphics, exam, bordermatrix

I'm learning Exam Class to generate question paper. Sample tex code is mentioned below:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt, text=white] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\circled{\thequestion}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[4] Choose the correct reponse: 
\begin{choices} \choice Option A
\choice Option B
\choice Option C
\choice Option D
 \end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Can you please give some direction to add questions [37 & Passage for 15-19] mentioned below:
[image: 37]

[image: Passage for 15-19]

Comment: `mdframed` for the boxes, `wrapfig` or some simple `minipages` should do get you started :)

Comment: Also see `\uplevel` in the `exam` documentation.

Comment: Also, the example given isn't logically consistent, which will be more difficult to reproduce in LaTeX.  Specifically, the entirety of question 37 is framed, whereas the others frame only a 'passage'.  (This latter framing is most certainly a duplicate, and can be integrated into `exam` without any special treatment.)

Comment: I do this sort of thing a lot (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets) but I do not use exam class, have no intention of ever using exam class, and do not want to read the manual.

Comment: The tricky part is not putting text into a rounded frame, but getting aligned with all the other questions.  The easiest way to do this is to put every question or text into a minipage with the same width and center them on the page.  Once again, this is not something you can do using exam class.

Comment: I broke down and read the manual.  You might be able to do it by using \uplevel and playing with the inner sep parameter for the rounded corners style and minipage width.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is part of the solution.  Obviously you would use your own clip art.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt, text=white] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\circled{\thequestion}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[4] Choose the correct reponse: 
\begin{choices} \choice Option A
\choice Option B
\choice Option C
\choice Option D
 \end{choices}

\hspace*{-0.27in}\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=5pt]
\path node[rectangle,draw=black] {\hspace*{.23in}\parbox{5.97in}{
\question[4] Choose the correct reponse: 
\begin{choices} \choice Option A
\choice Option B
\choice Option C
\choice Option D
\end{choices}
}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\hspace*{-0.27in}\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=5pt]
\path node[rectangle,draw=black] {\begin{minipage}{6.2in}
\begin{minipage}[c]{5in}
\raggedright\setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}
There are many kinds of boats.

One kind of boat is called a sailboat.  It uses wind to move.
Wind makes the sailboat move in the water.  
Wind pushes the sailboat.  Wind fills the sails.
The sailboat moves when the wind blows.
\end{minipage}\hfill\parbox[c]{1in}{\resizebox{1in}{!}{\includegraphics{sailboat.png}}}

\parbox[c]{1in}{\resizebox{1in}{!}{\includegraphics{motorboat.png}}}\hfill
\parbox[c]{5in}{\raggedright
One kind of boat is called a motorboat.
A motorboat uses a motor to move.
The motor gives power to the boat.
The motorboat moves when the motor is running,
The motor makes a loud noise.}

\parbox[c]{5in}{\raggedright
One kind of boat is called a rowboat.
A rowboat needs people to move it.
People make a rowboat move in the water.
People use oars to move a rowboat.
Oars are long and flat.
Oars go into the water.
A rowboat moves when people use the oars.
}\hfill\parbox[c]{1in}{\resizebox{1in}{!}{\includegraphics{rowboat.png}}}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: output page]

Comment: The problem with fitting the question inside the frame is that the question number is outside the margins.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a try with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}
%
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}
%
\newtcolorbox{myqbox}{%
  colback=white,
  left=-1ex, % left space between content text and box I don't know why -1ex is needed here
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  skin=freelance,
  enlarge left by=0pt,
  frame code={%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}    
    \draw[line width = 2pt,color = magenta,rounded corners=2ex] ($(frame.south west) +(-1.2\leftmargin,-.2em)$) rectangle ($(frame.north east)+(.3em,.2em)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}%
  },
}%
%
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{%
  colback=white,
  left=0ex, % left space between content text and box I don't know why -1ex is needed here
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  arc=2ex,
  oversize  
}%
%

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt, text=white] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\circled{\thequestion}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[4] Choose the correct reponse:
\begin{choices} \choice Option A
\choice Option B
\choice Option C
\choice Option D
\end{choices}
%
\begin{myqbox}%
\question[4] Choose the correct reponse just to fill the line of text until the end of line for having some fun and test:
\begin{choices} \choice Option A
\choice Option B
\choice Option C
\choice Option D
 \end{choices}
\end{myqbox}
%
\uplevel{%
{\bfseries Read the following and go to heaven}
\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
}
%
\begin{myqbox}%
\question[4] Choose the correct reponse just to fill the line of text until the end of line for having some fun and test:
\begin{choices} \choice Option A
\choice Option B
\choice Option C
\choice Option D
 \end{choices}
\end{myqbox}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Caveats:** If you want to add background color for questions, then you are in trouble. Also I don't understand why I have to add `left=-1ex,`.

Comment: Rounded corners need larger margins so that the text doesn't overlap the corner (hence the -1ex).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am afraid, it is not so.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that it wasn't needed for the \mybox.  Perhaps it is due to the line width.

Answer (score 2):

Considering how complex the above are, is the following all that difficult?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}

\newlength{\qwidth}
\setlength{\qwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\qwidth}{-0.75in}

\newcommand{\qbox}{\framebox[0.25in]{\rule{0in}{.2in}} \hspace*{0.1in}}

\newcommand{\question}[2]%#1 = problem number, #2 = statement
{(#1) \qbox
\parbox[t]{\qwidth}{\raggedright #2}
\par\vfill}

\newcommand{\qmult}[3]%#1 = number, #2 = question, #3 = choices
{(#1) \qbox \parbox[t]{\qwidth}{\raggedright #2}\par
\hspace*{0.1in}
\begin{tabular}{ll}#3\end{tabular}\\
\vfill}

\newcommand{\qchoice}[2]%#1 = letter, #2 = text
{#1.&#2\\}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\large
\framebox[3in][l]{\rule{0in}{0.25in}\tiny name}\hfill
\framebox[1.5in][l]{\rule{0in}{0.25in}\tiny date}\hfill
\framebox[0.4in][l]{\rule{0in}{0.25in}\tiny period}

\begin{center}
{\huge Attitude}
\end{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

Answer true (T) or false (F).
\par\vfill
\question{1}{I'm not going to learn anything, and you can't make me.}
\question{2}{If it's not about sports, video games, pop culture, me or
 my friends, I don't want to hear about it.}
\question{3}{If it's not going to be on the test, I don't need to know it.}
\question{4}{When I try to do math all I can think of is ``I hate this!  
 I hate this!  I hate this!''}
\question{5}{No one I know or admire is any good at math either.}
\question{6}{I enjoy solving puzzles.}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

Multiple choice.

\qmult{7}{I won't need an education if I am going to be  \underline{\rule{0.5in}{0pt}} .}{
\qchoice{A}{dead by 21}
\qchoice{B}{a convicted felon}
\qchoice{C}{in a permanent drunken stupor}
\qchoice{D}{on an MTV reality show}
}
\qmult{8}{Given a choice, I would rather be \underline{\rule{0.5in}{0pt}} .}{
\qchoice{A}{ignorant}
\qchoice{B}{narrow minded}
\qchoice{C}{self-destructive}
\qchoice{D}{unpopular}
}

\end{document}
```

BTW, I know how to use counters, I just don't like them.